# Text aggregate subquery in Oracle not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do text aggregation on a subquery..

The error message I am getting back is

missing WITHIN keyword

My code is

```
Select
    DISTINCT(sh.order_date) as OrderDate,
    sup.supplier_name as SupplierName,
    sh.sales_document_num as OrderNumber,
    pro.product_code as SKU,
    pro.long_description_1 as ProductName,
    po.order_number as PONumber,
    sh.delivery_name as Name,
    sh.address1 as Address1,
    sh.address2 as Address2,
    sh.address3 as City,
    sh.address5 as StateProv,
    sh.POSTCODE as Postalcode,
    sh.country_code as Country,
    sh.inv_contact_telephone_1 as Phone,
    sh.inv_contact_email as Email,                             
    'TBC' as SupplierDesc,
    pi.order_required as Quantity,
    (select LISTAGG(LARGE_TEXT) from sales_entity_data  where entity_key1 = '20817159') as Personlization,
    'TBC' as LeadTime
from
    sales_header sh
    left join customer c on sh.customer_account = c.customer_account
    left join sales_item si on sh.sales_document_num = si.sales_document_num
    inner join po_header po on sh.sales_document_num = po.sales_document_num
    left join product pro on si.product_code = pro.product_code
    left join po_item pi on po.order_number = pi.order_number and si.product_code = pi.product_code 
     and si.order_quantity = pi.order_required
    left join supplier sup ON po.supplier_account = sup.supplier_account
where
    Sh.sales_document_num = '20817159'
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) for LISTAGG

Comment: Thanks, Yep got it working.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra brackets and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT sh.order_date as OrderDate, ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Thanks Jarl .. will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
select LISTAGG(LARGE_TEXT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LARGE_TEXT)
---------------------------^ separator
--------------------------------^ ordering
```

That said, the limit for `LISTAGG()` is a result of 2000 characters, so you may not be able to aggregate "large" text.